# opening two remote screen sharing on the same client

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, screen-sharing

I have a macbook and I connect to my linux accounts with `screen sharing`. I would like to connect to two different linux accounts from the same client (my macbook) at the same time, using two different instances of `screen sharing`. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a *New Connection*

For the purposes of answering this question, I have connected to two separate Macs - an XServe that I use for Dev purposes and a colleagues MacBook Pro - at the same time.  All my FreeBSD (alternative to Linux)  servers are "headless" and have no GUIs installed - everything is done via command line, so I can't show it connecting to a *nix machine GUI specifically.

[image: Two Screens]

To do this, just open a new session in Screen Sharing by clicking "New" on the Screen Sharing menu (top bar) or in Connect to Server (<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) and entering `vnc://<servername or ip address>`

I haven't tested the limit, but I am sure you can add more screens as needed.